# Depth and codepth of an algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra over a field $K$ and
$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow \cdots$
a minimal injective coresolution of the regular module $A$.
The dominant dimension domdim A of $A$ is defined as the smallest $n$ such that $I^n$ is not projective or as infinite if no such n exists.

The grade $gr S$ of a simple $A$-module $S$ is defined as $\inf \{ i \geq 0 \mid Ext_A^i(S,A) \neq 0 \}$ and dually the cograde $cogr S$ of a simple module $S$ is defined as $\inf \{ i \geq 0 \mid Ext_A^i(D(A),S) \neq 0 \}$, where $D(A)=Hom_A(A,K)$.

The depth of $A$ is defined as the maximum of the grades of the simple $A$-modules and the codepth of $A$ is defined as the maximum of all cograde of the simple $A$-modules.

> Question: Assume $A$ has postivite dominant dimension and domdim A= depth A. Do we automatically have codepth A= domdim A ?

If this is true, then we would automatically have that also the left and right finitistic dimension of A is equal to domdim A.

My guess is that there is a simple counterexample or maybe this is related to some homological conjectures. But maybe there is also an easy proof.

Note that depth A= domdim A is equivalent to that we have a minimal injective coresolution (n=domdim A>0) of A as follows:
$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow I^{n-1} \rightarrow I^n \rightarrow \cdots $

such that $I^i$ are projective-injective for $i=0,1,...,n-1$ and all other non-projective indecomposable injective A-modules are direct summands of $I^n$.

The questions asks whether then automatically the opposite algebra of $A$ has the same property. It is known that the dominant dimension of $A$ coincides with the dominant dimension of the opposite algebra.